# Help translating this paragraph: doubts about 「への」and「と共に」forms, and structure of a sentence beggining with 「これ」?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, syntax, adverbs

The paragraph is from the introduction to the wikipedia article on David Ben-Gurion:

> ポーランドのプロニスクで生まれ、パレスチナ移住後はユダヤ系住民のイギリス軍への参加を呼びかけると共に、ナチスの弾圧によって多くのユダヤ系難民がパレスチナへ押し寄せる様になると、これを規制しようとするイギリス当局と折衝して難民受け入れに尽力した。

My intent of translation from which i want you to show me errors specially on structure, what is being difficult for me to recognize the correct one, is this:

*Born in Płońsk in Poland, after the migration over Palestine he called for the participation of the British army in charge of the jewish citizens, minding that due to nazis oppression many Jewish people were settling into Palestine, to try to make policing of those (jewish refugees) by British authorities and to put effort on the negotiation of their acceptance.*

I saw other possible interpretations that said it means something different, so I could say the previous translation was taken almost randomly from all those. In this translation I did the following:

1. I took へ　just as the directional particle and の modifying [参加]{sanka} as a way of referring to the 軍の参加, but this is totally and wrongly intuitive. its just that I cannot find any information for への.
2. I took と共に as applying to the next sentence instead of the sentence it is ending. So one of my questions is to which sentences does it apply? It did not make sense for me in applying it to the actual sentence.
3. I understood「これ」 to mean "those" as in those jewish immigrants

And the structure of all the sentences after これ are too hard for  me to understand. I have no idea of what criteria to use, and I fear that it's totally wrong.

Comment: First off, welcome to Japanese.se. There's a lot of errors in your English writing (not just in the part where you're translating) that might make it hard to tell whether the problem is Japanese to Spanish or Spanish to English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm generally pretty strict on these kinds of questions, but considering that this particular block of text is kind of dense and hard to understand, I'll offer some help in parsing it. I'll break it apart bit by bit.

> ポーランドのプロニスクで生まれ

Born in ~ Poland

> パレスチナ移住後はユダヤ系住民のイギリス軍への参加を呼びかけると共に

After emigrating to Palestine, he called for all Jewish residents to join the British army, and (while doing this)...

への is referring to イギリス軍. イギリス軍へ参加する is what it is as a verb, but since we're turning it into a noun to use it as an object, we attach the の to the へ to make it イギリス軍への参加 (which is like イギリス軍へ参加すること). Don't think of へ as being purely lieral in its "directional" meaning. It has a more abstract and metaphorical sense of direction as well, like in "going into the army" or something. The とともに just says that he was doing these things concurrently.

> ナチスの弾圧によって多くのユダヤ系難民がパレスチナへ押し寄せる様になると

When many Jews seeking refuge from Nazi oppression approached (bore down on, put pressure on, basically moved toward and tried to enter) Palestine

> これを規制しようとするイギリス当局と折衝して難民受け入れに尽力した。

In an effort to control (mitigate, regulate) this he negotiated with British authorities to have them accept refugees. これ refers to the mass influx of refugees into Palestine.

Note that Palestine was under British control at this time.

Reassembling this into a coherent passage is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: AFAIK への is about the only way to make an adnominal out of に in certain situations (like this) - that's probably why it's used with 参加.

Comment: Good point - I didn't even realize the oddness of saying にの